# Search with ajax on click and show results in same page laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I've setup a view which contains a search form:

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" id="product_id" value="{{$tour->id}}">
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label>Date:</label>
    <div class="input-group date">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="start"  placeholder="Start Date">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label>End:</label>
    <div class="input-group date">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right"  id="end" placeholder="End Date">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4" id="dateprice-search">
    <label></label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" id="btn-search" >
        Search
    </button>
</div>
```

The below is the ajax code to handle the request of the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#dateprice-search').on('click', '#btn-search', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/date-price',
        data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            'product_id': $("#product_id").val(),
            'start': $("#start").val(),
            'end': $("#end").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.shadow-z-1').show();
            $('.shadow-z-1').append("<tr class='liquid-row><td>" + data.start + "</td><td>"+ data.end + "</td><td>" + data.end + "</td><td><a class='btn-m btn btn-m-success'>Available</a></td></tr>");

        }
    });
  });
});
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/date-price','GetPublicController@datePrice')
->name('searchDate');
```

And finally method in controller to give the results:

```
    public function datePrice(Request $request){
    $start = $request->start;
    $end = $request->end;

    $dates = DatePrice::where('tour_id','=',$request->product_id)
    ->whereBetween('start', array($request->start, $request->end))
    ->whereBetween('end', array($request->start, $request->end))
    ->get();
    return response()->json($dates);
}
```

At first the url looks like this before submitting the form `http://localhost:8000/trips/popular/trekking/test` and url becomes `http://localhost:8000/trips/popular/trekking/test?` after clicking the search button. Console section of inspect element shows no error in script. What mistake I had made over here ?

Comment: it mean your form submiting to same page due to type="submit"

Answer (score 1):

It mean your form `submiting` to same page due to `type="submit"`

1) change to `type="button"`

```
 <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-search" >
```

2) Here `click event` should be for `button` not to `div` so change the `selector`  and add `e.preventDefault();` in jquery to prevent the default submit .

`$('#btn-search').on('click', '#btn-search', function() { e.preventDefault();   });`

**note :**

**1st** : your `action attribute` missing so form will be submit same page .

**2nd** : your `method attribute` missing so it will take default `GET` method

Answer (score 0):

You have given button type as `submit`, either remove it as

```
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-search" >
    Search
</button>
```

or use the jquery `preventDeafult()` function to prevent the default behavior of submit button i.e form submit in your button click event as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#dateprice-search').on('click', '#btn-search', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //your ajax code
  });
});
```