# AJAX response only feedbacks the object and not the actual data

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, response

I'm very nearly there. I've simply created a search feature for my web application that allows the Administrator to search for users. Upon searching, the AJAX object returns as it should. However, when trying to output it to my table body or row, nothing seems to show apart from the table  elements. I'm sure I'm missing out on one small thing?

I've tried accessing the data using "data.name" but then nothing happens at all, but if I leave it as "data" then it moves to a blank table with no information. I'm not sure whether it should display the requests information in the table or if I'm meant to then create additional  rows for each element returned. So I've looked at:

[Search with ajax on click and show results in same page laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672441/search-with-ajax-on-click-and-show-results-in-same-page-laravel)

as I'm using Laravel. Anyhow I'll post my code below.

Controller

```
public function searchUser(){
        $term = request()->input('user');
        $search = User::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')->paginate(10);
        return response()->json($search);
    }
```

View & JS

```
<form class="form-inline" id="user-search">
                    @csrf
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search by name or username"
                           name='search-user' id="search" style="width: 16rem;">
                    <button class="btn" type="button" id="find-user"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#find-user').on('click', function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $.ajaxSetup({
                                headers: {
                                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                                }
                            });
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "{{route('admin.search')}}",
                                type: 'GET',
                                data: {user: jQuery('#search').val()},
                                success: function (data) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                   $('tbody').html(data);
                                }
                            });
                        })
                    });
                </script>
```

Table to display results

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="main-table">
                    <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Username</th>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($users as $u)
                    <tr class="test">
                        <td>{{$u->username}}</td>
                        <td>{{$u->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$u->email}}</td>
                     </tbody>
</table>
```

Also it reports back the searched object using console.log, so I know my controller is working fine it's just trying to convert that JSON into actual readable output?

Comment: In this line `$('tbody').html(data);` is `data` valid HTML? If you're returning `response()->json($search)`, which is the result of `->paginate(10)`, I highly doubt it.

Comment: Yes data is what's being returned from search with paginate. So are you saying its due to my paginate function?

Comment: Sorta, yeah. `->paginate()` doesn't return anything that can be directly converted to HTML, so using `$("...").html(data);` isn't going to do anything. You have to manipulate `data` in your JS function to produce valid HTML to pass to `.html()`, or change your Controller logic to produce the raw HTML for you.

Comment: You need to build a <tr> first, them replace the $('tbody').html().

Comment: @TimLewis but the data is being received through paginate as it would as a normal User::all() collection? so why would it make it different?

Comment: Look at your code; you're manipulating the data in PHP using `@foreach` to loop and convert it to `<tr>` and `<td>` elements. You need to do the same in JS :)

Comment: @TimLewis Okay I believe I understand now. One more thing though, is how am I meant to access a single value before I create my rows?? e.g. "data.name" < name being a value from the returned object, or data['name'] or 0 doesn't seem to work?

Comment: No worries. And you'll need to loop. Something like `data.users.forEach(function(user){ // user.name, etc. });` You'll have to see what `console.log(data)` returns (which you have in your code; so use that as reference)

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of the loop business I found out about that before :D, just trying to access a single field. Okay i'll see if I can retrieve it yet nothing seems to be working atm. Thank you. EDIT: Nvm thought I had to convert it but apparently it's already in JSON format.

Comment: Happy to help! If you run into any further issues, feel free to update your question with the new code you're using and any errors you might be getting. Best of luck!

Comment: Perhaps try like this: `response()->json(["search" => $search]);`, then try accessing `data.search`; you should be able to loop over that. Might be easier if you update your question with the actual content of `console.log(data)` (or, after the change, `console.log(data.search)`

Comment: Okay I'll give ^ a try and ill show you my code next time. Turned out it was showing data[0] because at the moment I'm i've only got 2 users, so when it matches ONE its only one element of course. But if i search as an empty string it returns data with [2]. Returning at as Search still works, and returns the object as data.search or just data, but still cant access my fields

Comment: Think I've sorted it. The JSON resposne was returning the full object so I used the search key to access the array like so: console.log(data.search.data[0].name);            I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113215/ajax-read-json-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined